Create Organisation Repository in workflows
I want to create a new Repository when a new issue with a certain label is created.
The repo muss be created in an Organisation where I'm admin
I found this repo and tried to use it but it was deprecated.
So I instead tried with this:
env:
    ORG_NAME: 'Test-Org'
    NEW_REPO_NAME: ${{ github.event.issue.title }}
    GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ORG_ADMIN_TOKEN }}
run: |
    gh repo create $ORG_NAME/$NEW_REPO_NAME --public
    

This job failled with this error accepts at most 1 arg(s), received 4
Any idea of why the repo is not created?

It may be related to the ${{ github.event.issue.title }} variable. What was the value used in the workflow run? If there are spaces in the issue title, you will have something like: gh repo create org/word1 word2 word3 word4 --public, which would indeed return this error message.

Thanks, I added a tr ' ' '-' and now its works fine
